# Elasticsearch multi match exact phrase on all fields

Tags: elasticsearch, match, phrase

We currently have a query like this:

```
                    "query": {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "john doe",
                             analyzer: "whitespace",
                             type: "most_fields",

                        }
                    }
```

Basically this searches for "john" or "doe" across all fields in the document.

How can we search for exactly "john doe" in all fields?

This is the best I can do so far:

```
                    "query": {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "john doe",
                            "type": "phrase", 
                        }
                    }
```

Unfortunately this searches for "john" and "doe" within one field. It does not search for the exact phrase "john doe" within a field.

Is there no way to do this other than to duplicate all the fields into one big field containing all the values? Then run a standard match_phrase query on that field?

Here is a sample of the index with dummy field names:

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "@timestamp": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "@version": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "date1": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "date2": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "text1": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "text2": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "text3": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Sample data (real data is super standard and flattened strings)

```
{
    "_index": "myIndex",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "013345",
    "_score": 7.414526,
    "_source": {
        "date1": "2017-05220T03:59:59.000Z",
        "text1": "Available ",
        "text2": "Hello i am john doe",
        "text3": "Ministry",
        "text4": "Decision",
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please explain this **It does not search for the exact phrase "john doe" within a field.**

Comment: @ESCoder the query is returning all documents that contain "john" and "doe" within the same field instead of an exact match on "john doe"

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "name": "b",
  "user": "john doe is great"
}
{
  "name": "john doe",
  "user": "a"
}
{
  "name": "b",
  "user": "john is doe great"
}
```

**Search Query:**

This query searches for the exact phrase `"john doe"` across all fields.

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "john doe",
      "type": "phrase"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66129712",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.1784627,
        "_source": {
          "name": "john doe",
          "user": "a"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66129712",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.50632054,
        "_source": {
          "name": "b",
          "user": "john doe is great"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I am using the exact same query but it isnt working for me. My data is returning a bunch of results, only one of which has exactly "john doe". Any ideas please?

Comment: @AllenH. can you please share your index mapping, sample index data as well ?

Comment: how can I find my index mapping please?

Comment: @AllenH. you can get your index mapping by `GET /<your-index-name>/_mapping`

Refer to this documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html

Comment: Thanks, I updated the OP with the index info. It is mostly vanilla string and date objects, no customizations I think. The data is also super standard.

Comment: @AllenH. Index mapping looks fine, can you please share some sample index data also ?

Comment: Thanks @ESCoder, I added it to the OP. The data is vanilla key-value pairs, im not sure what to look for specifically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228508/discussion-between-escoder-and-allen-h).

Comment: @AllenH. can you please accept and upvote the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue :)

Comment: it didnt resolve the issue unfortunately. I Went into the chat but I didnt see your reply?

Comment: @AllenH. apologies for the delayed response. Have you tried the multi-match query?